# Is it possible to replace one directive with another one

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to create a substitution (or similar) that transforms one directive into another.

For example:

In our sphinx based documentation, we use [Admonitions](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#admonitions) to create certain note and warning boxes.

However, if we use

```
.. note:: This is a Note
```

The title of the box is *Note*, and *This is a Note* becomes the first paragraph.

In contrast, this directive

```
.. admonition:: This is a Note
   :class: note
```

produces a note box with the desired title.

To make it easier for other editors, I would like to create a substitution, that replaces the first with the second.

Is there anything this can be done with in sphinx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. You have to add a custom directive to Sphinx. Create a Python module (like `mydirectives.py` next to `conf.py`) with the following:

```py
import os
import os.path
import re
import subprocess

import docutils.core
import docutils.nodes
import docutils.parsers.rst

class AbstractDirective(docutils.parsers.rst.Directive):
    has_content = True
    required_arguments = 0
    optional_arguments = 0
    option_spec = {}
    final_argument_whitespace = False

    node_class = docutils.nodes.container

    def run(self):
        self.assert_has_content()
        text = '\n'.join(self.content)
        admonition_node = self.node_class(rawsource=text)
        self.state.nested_parse(self.content, self.content_offset,
                                admonition_node)
        admonition_node.set_class("abstract")
        return [admonition_node]


def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('abstract', AbstractDirective)
```

There must be some way to add the title as well. Perhaps you need to add a
title node yourself. The documentation is lacking there, best look at the
[source for
admonitions](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docutils/parsers/rst/directives/admonitions.py)
and you will get a feel for the docutils.

With a custom text node you should be able to make up your own note directive.

Comment: To avoid a warning when registering an existing directive set parameter `override` to `True`: `app.add_directive('note', AbstractDirective, override=True)`.